# c# byte[] asspan equivalent?

Tags: c#, io, .net-4.7.2

I have a line of code with an AsSpan method that didn't exist in .NET 4.7.2.
This is from a netstandard2.1 project that I neither understand nor can convert to .NET 4.7.2.

I found out that the "AsSpan" method is possible using the System.Memory NuGet package. However, the Write method then requires an offset and count. Unfortunately, I have no idea about file operations.

Can someone help me please? It should run under Mono .NET 4.7.2.

```cs
class Packer
{
    public byte[] Bytes { get; }
    // ...
    public override void Pack(Stream destination)
    {
        destination.Write(Bytes.AsSpan());
    }
}
```

Comment: `destination.Write(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected, the other version of [`Stream.Write`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.write) would do the trick.

> `offset`
>
> The zero-based byte offset in buffer at which to begin copying bytes to the current stream.

You want to write every byte in the array, so you want to start with the first, or an offset of `0`.

> `count`
>
> The number of bytes to be written to the current stream

You want to write every byte in the array, soy you want to write `Bytes.Length` bytes.

```cs
destination.Write(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length);
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Spans didn't exist in .NET Framework 4.8, so that only leaves `Stream.Write(Byte[], Int32, Int32)`.

Comment: @ikegami I believe spans can be added to .NET Framework app via [`System.Memory`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/) nuget. Though AFAIK they will not provide the same level of performance boost. And quite sure that `Stream.Write` overload will not be present.